# Using a selected item from a DropDownList in a query

Tags: sql, asp.net, select, drop-down-menu

I am trying to use the selected item from a drop down list in a SELECT query. Here is my code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT tblAirport.Name, tblFlight.Destination, tblFlight.FlightDate FROM tblAirport INNER JOIN tblFlight ON tblAirport.AirportCode = tblFlight.AirportCode WHERE Destination = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

However from this code I get errors when selecting an item:

> "DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value" could not be bound.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

`<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT tblAirport.Name, tblFlight.Destination, tblFlight.FlightDate FROM tblAirport INNER JOIN tblFlight ON tblAirport.AirportCode = tblFlight.AirportCode WHERE (Destination = @Destination)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="Destination" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>`